# What tick is right before 0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have tried using /time query daytime to find out an estimate but I am trying to make a redstone Calendar and I need to activate it right before daytime tick 0 so I can restart the Tick Counter.

> /title @a[score_time_min=X] title {text:"Date Goes Here",color:blue,bold:true}

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not asking how to use the '/time query daytime' command I already know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 24000 ticks in a full day, so 23999 would be the tick before 0.

Keep in mind that `/time query daytime` currently seems broken and never restarts from 0, it keeps going. You'll need to add in the modulus using scoreboards.

Comment: Thanks, I have a scoreboard setup called "time" and every tick adds 1 to the "time" objective. and I needed to set the command to output a redstone signal when the time hit X (Tick Before 0).